# Java Comparator will calculate score 1 time or several times

Tags: java

I need to sort a list with my custom comparator: `Collections.sort(availableItems, new TextClassifyCnnComparator(citem, false))`

```
class TextClassifyCnnComparator implements Comparator<Item> {

    private Item citem;
    private boolean isAsc;

    public TextClassifyCnnComparator(Item citem) {
        this(citem, true);
    }

    public TextClassifyCnnComparator(Item citem, boolean isAsc) {
        this.citem = citem;
        this.isAsc = isAsc;
    }

    private Double calcSimilarScore(Item item) {
        return item.getEncodedFromCNN().dotProduct(citem.getEncodedFromCNN());
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        if (isAsc) {
            return calcSimilarScore(o1).compareTo(calcSimilarScore(o2));
        }
        return calcSimilarScore(o2).compareTo(calcSimilarScore(o1));
    }

}
```

Will Java map and call `calcSimilarScore` 1 time for each item or it would be called several times (1 for each tuple 2 item)?

If it call several times, how can I optimize this task?

========= Update 1: ===============

I have refract my comparator in this:

```
class TextClassifyCnnComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {

    private boolean isAsc;
    private List<Double> list;

    public TextClassifyCnnComparator(Item citem, List<Item> list) {
        this(citem, list, true);
    }

    public TextClassifyCnnComparator(Item citem, List<Item> list, boolean isAsc) {
        this.list = list.parallelStream().map(item -> calcSimilarScore(item, citem)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.isAsc = isAsc;
    }

    private Double calcSimilarScore(Item item1, Item item2) {
        return item1.getEncodedFromCNN().dotProduct(item2.getEncodedFromCNN());
    }

    public List<Integer> createIndexes() {
        List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            indexes.add(i); // Autoboxing
        }
        return indexes;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer index1, Integer index2) {
        // Autounbox from Integer to int to use as array indexes
        if (isAsc)
            return list.get(index1).compareTo(list.get(index2));
        return list.get(index2).compareTo(list.get(index1));
    }

}
```

...

```
TextClassifyCnnComparator comparator = new TextClassifyCnnComparator(citem, availableItems);
List<Integer> indexes = comparator.createIndexes();
Collections.sort(indexes, comparator);

return indexes.parallelStream().map(index -> availableItems.get(index)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I think it still can be optimized more.

Comment: Comparator compares two objects that are passed to `compare()` method, why is your comparator's constructor accepts an `Item` as an argument? and why would you expect us to know how to optimize code that we haven't seen (such as `getEncodedFromCNN()` and `dotProduct()`) ?

Comment: @alfasin i want to compare similar score between that `Item` with each `Item` in list. Is that a problem? don't care too much about anything inside `calcSimilarScore ` function

Comment: You can compare any two items by calling `compare()` on the two, but here you're creating a comparator per Item which seems wrong, or even misleading, because the two items that are passed to compare are not compared against each other, but against a third item and then the results are compared.

Comment: Of course it needs to compare the same element to several other ones (just putting a System.out.println() in the code would allow you to find that out by yourself). If you want to avoid that, compute all the scores first, stor them with the objects to compare, and reuse the already computed score to compare elements.

Comment: @JBNizet do you have any suggestion to optimize this task? It is a matrix operator, I don't want to compute many times.

Comment: I have. Read my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following optimizations:

- One should use `double` (the "primitive" data type) instead of `Double` (the Object wrapper class holding a double), wherever feasible.
- Of the compared `citem` a part can be precalculated in the constructor. (`citem` might even not be needed anymore as field.)
- A value may be compared several times, so a cache is possible, a Map from Item to its double value.

So

```
class TextClassifyCnnComparator implements Comparator<Item> {

    private final Item citem;
    private final boolean isAsc;
    private final ECNN encodedFromCNN;

    private Map<Item, Double> scores = new HashMap<>();

    public TextClassifyCnnComparator(Item citem) {
        this(citem, true);
    }

    public TextClassifyCnnComparator(Item citem, boolean isAsc) {
        this.citem = citem;
        this.isAsc = isAsc;
        encodedFromCNN = citem.getEncodedFromCNN();
    }

    private double calcSimilarScore(Item item) {
        Double cached = scores.get(item);
        if (cached != null) {
            return cached;
        }
        double score = item.getEncodedFromCNN().dotProduct(encodedFromCNN);
        scores.put(Item, score);
        return score;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        if (isAsc) {
            return calcSimilarScore(o1).compareTo(calcSimilarScore(o2));
        }
        return calcSimilarScore(o2).compareTo(calcSimilarScore(o1));
    }

}
```

Or stylish in java 8:

```
    private double calcSimilarScore(Item item) {
        return scores.computeIfAbsent(item,
            it -> it.getEncodedFromCNN().dotProduct(encodedFromCNN));
    }
```